# CSS stylesheets are not referencing properly in browser, but they are in my IDE

Tags: html, css, browser

I have been trying to reference a stylesheet in the same folder, and it works on some pages, but not others. All are in the same folder, and the IDE (Code) recognizes them properly. The browser (Chrome and I.E.) does not. I tested this mostly from my local files, but also from the http site at an earlier time (currently the upload system is having hallucinations of some kind, see below) Files are in the same folder, spelling is certainly correct.
Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><link href="example.css" type="text/css"></head>
<body><p>I am not formatted.</p></body>
</html>
```

Css:
    p {color: blue;}

This type of code works on 2 out of 8 files. I honestly have no clue what would cause this, and have been searching for several weeks for a solution. Any help, explanations, or workarounds would be greatly appreciated. As a secondary problem, the upload service is turning things chinese and deleting other things, but this has never happened before so I will assume for now that it is an error on the hosting service's end. Here is the site: www.whsunc.gq/contact.html
(I apologize for any formatting errors, let me know about them and I will fix them.)

Comment: I like the part where you provided no code or anything to help you.

Comment: In the browser's debugging tools, what is the server's response when the style sheet is requested?  What is the full URL of the request?  What happens when you enter that URL manually in the address bar?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can see the code, I am unsure why you can't. This is my first time, I'll edit it in.

Comment: Do you have a link to the public version that is not working we could check out ?

Comment: It makes no difference to type it manually, and the I have a workaround (Copy pasted the css) in the actual site, I'll upload the current version.

Comment: Upon uploading, things have turned Chinese. I am totally lost. It shows that it should be that way in the debugger, but that is certainly not what I uploaded. http://whsunc.gq/contact.html

Comment: Additionally, what could I do to improve my post? Apparently I did something terribly wrong. I would like this to be as informative as possible.

Comment: @EthanReese On improving your post: _Ideally_, a question should contain _all the information needed to solve the problem_. Of course, since you don't know what the problem is (or you wouldn't be asking), you can't tell, but here's what I'd post if I were in your position: (1) The listing of of the files in the directory. (2) Whether you're testing via `file:` or `http:`. (3) Any messages shown in the browser's developer console. All of these things should be copied and pasted or screenshot-ed if necessary, but _not_ retyped, to make sure no misleading typos happen. Hope this advice helps!

Comment: Oh, and another thing that would be a good idea is to create a complete _short_ example for reproducing the problem: a short HTML document (that contains the stylesheet and some text for it to style) and a short stylesheet, and add those to your question. (The exercise of creating such reduced test cases often helps developers find their own problems!)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'll start putting that in.

Comment: Please add the contents of the browser's console when you visit the page.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the link relation part on the two that works and paste them into the other 6. Paste your code into a html validator https://validator.w3.org/ to ensure it is correct.

Failing that, try it in a new browser and failing that, a new code editor.

Comment: I am trying that now!

Comment: Thank you, but it appears to just identify the errors that it made upon uploading, which has turned into a nothing problem entirely.

Comment: try that site and see if it gives any insight to the problem

Comment: Thanks again, but I think my referencing is fine- it works on some pages and I simply copy-pasted the link html. I am trying to figure out why it isn't working for specific pages.  I have checked that particular part more than I wanted too, and even asked a professional web developer what the issue was, and he determined it wasn't due to that.

Comment: Yes, in simple notepad, notepad++, and two different browsers.